# difference between html webpage and html email newsletter

Tags: html

What is the difference in terms of the html code for an html webpage and an html newsletter. Why do we always use tables in html news letters and not divs?

Answer (score 5):

> Why do we always use tables in html news letters and not divs?

The HTML / CSS rendering engines in some common email clients are not as good as the HTML / CSS rendering engines in all common web browsers (or in the case of Microsoft Outlook … are [simply dreadful](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2393/microsoft-takes-email-design-b/)).

Comment: +1 and probably Word HTML parser in Outlook is a big part of that :)

Comment: To add to this answer, you might find this article helpful as it outlines best practices to follow when writing HTML for emails. http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/2010/01/23/09.27.00/